# Какие ставятся вопросы к придаточным, и какие сами придаточные?

Tags: придаточное-предложение

*Мне кажется, что, если я сделаю ещё хоть один шаг среди этой грозной темноты, я тоже полечу в глубокую трясину.*

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется что? — *я тоже полечу в глубокую трясину* (придаточное изъяснительное).

Я тоже полечу в глубокую трясину при каком условии? — *если я сделаю ещё хоть один шаг среди этой грозной темноты* (придаточное условия).